Azure PowerShell: 404 Not Found when calling Microsoft.DomainRegistration/generateSsoRequest
I'm attempting to set up Cloudflare to host Azure domain names, following the process outlined in a Microsoft Q&A article.
As part of this process, I need to generate an SSO request for Azure Domain Registration using PowerShell. However, I'm encountering a 404 Not Found error when trying to call the Microsoft.DomainRegistration/generateSsoRequest endpoint. This is preventing me from proceeding with the Cloudflare setup for my Azure domains.
I tried running the following PowerShell code, both locally and in the Azure Portal's Cloud Shell:
$subscriptionID = "**********************"
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId **********************
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionID
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token"}
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/providers/Microsoft.DomainRegistration/generateSsoRequest?api-version=2023-01-01"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

I expected this code to successfully generate an SSO request, which I could then use to continue the process of setting up Cloudflare for my Azure domains. Instead, I received the following error:

Invoke-WebRequest: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

I verified that I'm connected to the correct Azure account and subscription, and that I'm using the latest API version (2023-01-01). Despite these checks, the error persists both in my local environment and in the Azure Portal's Cloud Shell. I'm unsure if the endpoint is correct or if there are additional permissions or configurations needed to make this request successfully.

You do not have the permission to access the Route. Most likely the Authorization is not allowed on the route. Solution is either to add the Role to the route in the server or use a different Role. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I tried the suggested commands:
Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DomainRegistration
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DomainRegistration
However, the result remained unchanged. I'm still encountering the same error when attempting to generate the SSO request.

The problem has to be fixed at server.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/troubleshooting?tabs=bicep

Are you still facing the issue? @Hayaaaaaa


404 Not Found when calling Microsoft.DomainRegistration/generateSsoRequest:

404 error found due to the below given reasons. Check below:
Firstly, open the portal and check if you have necessary administrative privileges to create a domain service and generate a sso request. If it is showing in the below way, then you are not eligible to perform operations, and it might show http error codes.

According to the MSDoc,


You need  Application Administrator  and  Groups Administrator  Microsoft Entra roles in your tenant to enable Domain Services.


Also you can check this MSDoc suggested by @jdweng for RBAC role related issues.
Check the API version of the resource provider again and also try calling it with the Invoke-RestMethod instead of web request to validate it.
If still the issue persists, you can use Cloudflare Workers to send custom HTTP headers which is detailed in this blog rather than generating a sso request approach.

Thanks for your answer, I am still facing the same problem. I am still facing the same problem. My account has been granted “Application Development Administrator”, “Group Administrator”, and “Global Administrator” permissions. creation of Microsoft Entra Domain Service is normal I believe, as the creation screen displays correctly.

Are you still facing the same issue. @Hayaaaaaa

Yes, Im still faced this problem. (upper comment)
